# UBUNTU 18.04, LOGIN LOOP

Tags: 18.04

I have just installed Ubuntu 18.04 in my laptop, then I restarted the computer and the purple page remained frozen after entering the password. 
Need solution !

Comment: Do you have Nvidia hardware?  Did you try adding "nomodeset" on the grub line at the "quiet splash" location (editing inst. at bottom of grub page)?